# id undefined when details are passed to a modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I have a table of recipes created by a particular user, and when the pencil mark on each row of the table is clicked, a modal is displayed, showing the details of this particular recipe and it should allow the user to edit the recipe and save the updated version to the database. However, although the details are correctly being passed to the modal, the recipe id doesn't seem to be passed to the modal, since I have tried to output the recipe id into the console and it says the recipe id is undefined. I have tried to debug this error but to no avail. Can anyone provide any insight into why this might be?

```
 //Recipe.js    

     $('.editThis').on('click', function() {
             var recipe_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
              var request = $.ajax({
                  url: "ajax/displayRecipe.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {recipe_id : recipe_id}
            });

            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
              console.log("response " + JSON.stringify(response));
              $('#name').val(response.name);
              $('#date').val(response.date);
                });

        });


    $('#editRecipe').click(function() {
      var recipe_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var name_input = $('#name').val();
        var date_input = $('#date').val();

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/updateRecipe.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {name : name_input, date : date_input, recipe_id : recipe_id},
            dataType: 'json'
        });

     request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
         console.log(response);

        });
    });

   //Recipe.php

    <?php

      $recipeObject = new recipeList($database); //Lets pass through our DB connection
      $recipe = $recipeObject->getUserRecipes($_SESSION['userData']['user_id']); 

      foreach ($recipe as $key => $recipes) { 
           echo '<tr><td>'. $value['name'].'</td><td>'. $value['date'].'</td><td>'.'<a data-id = '.$value['recip_id'].' data-toggle="modal" class="edit editThis" data-target="#editRecipe"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>'.'</td></tr>';
      }
    ?>

    // editRecipe Modal

    <div id="recipe" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header recipe">
                    <h1 class="modal-title">Edit Recipe</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post" id="updateRecipeForm">

                   <?php
                       require_once('classes/recipes.classes.php');
                       $recipeObject = new recipeList($database);
                       $recipe = $recipeObject->getRecipeDetails(recipe_id); 
                       if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                          $updateRecipe = $recipeObject ->updateRecipe($_POST['name'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['recipe_id']);
                          if($updateRecipe) {
                            echo ("Your recipe has been updated!";
                          }
                       }  
                   ?>

                   <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="control-form" id="name" value = "<?php echo $recipe['name']; ?>">
                   </div> 
                   <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="date" class="control-form" id="date" value = "<?php echo $recipe['date']; ?>">
                   </div>
                   </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <input type="hidden" class="form-control" data-id=".$recipe['recipe_id']." id="recipe_id" name="recipe_id" value = "<?php echo $recipe['recipe_id']; ?>">
                      </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn recipe" id="editRecipe" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
               </form>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>


//ajax - updateRecipe.php



     <?php
        require_once('../includes/database.php');
        require_once('../classes/recipes.classes.php');

        if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['date'] && $_POST['trans_id']){
            $recipeObject = new recipeList($database);
            echo $recipeObject->updateRecipe($_POST['name'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['recipe_id']);
        }
    ?>

//recipes.classes.php
    ...

    public function getRecipeDetails($recipeid){
             $query = "SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE recipe_id = :recipe_id";
                $pdo = $this->db->prepare($query);
                $pdo->bindParam(':recipe_id', $recipeid);
                $pdo->execute();
                return $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function updateRecipe($name, $date, $recipe_id){
            $query = "UPDATE recipe SET name = :name, date = :date WHERE recipe_id = :recipe_id";
            $pdo = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $pdo->bindParam(':name', $name);
            $pdo->bindParam(':date', $date);
            $pdo->bindParam(':recipe_id', $recipe_id);
            $pdo->execute();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Try this onclik function*

> Some time you cant get the apt value from **this** So Try this method.
>   we can use id but in your case you foreach the **a tag** so we cant repeat **id**. Hope Its Works

```
   <a data-toggle="modal" class="recipe_<?php echo $value['recipe_id']; ?> edit editThis" onclick="editRecipe('<?php echo $value['recipe_id']; ?>')" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>



function editRecipe(txt) {
      var recipe_id = $('.recipe_'+txt).val();
        var name_input = $('#name').val();
        var date_input = $('#date').val();

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/updateRecipe.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {name : name_input, date : date_input, recipe_id : recipe_id},
            dataType: 'json'
        });

     request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
         console.log(response);

        });
    };
```

Comment: should it be recipe_id instead of recip_id?

Comment: Whats your DB value whether its recipe_id or recip_id?

Comment: the value is recipe_id

Comment: Yeah i updated my answer, hope it works, If you have any issue, Please post a comment

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'recipe_id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' onclick="editRecipe('<?php echo $value["recipe_id"]; ?>')"

Comment: How does that overcome the syntax error out of curiosity?

Comment: I changed the a tag now check it

Comment: Please check it now, Replace the <a> tag like this <a data-toggle="modal" class="recipe_<?php echo $value['recipe_id']; ?> edit editThis" onclick="editRecipe('<?php echo $value['recipe_id']; ?>')" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>

Comment: Its working or not?? If its working then approve my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.editThis',function() {...});
$(document).on('click','#editRecipe',function() {...});
```